# How to run process which only attach stdin, stdout and stderr to another running process

Tags: linux, process, pipe, stdin

I have application which spawns child process ans used stdin/stdout/stderr to communicate with it. I can modify a spawn command.

What I would like to achieve is run this child process manually before spawn from application (eg because I want to run in debugger) and attach to it with standard spawn.

Is it possible?
I know there is /proc/PID/fd/0 and so on. But I still don't know if it's possible to connect it by spawning another "mock process" to it.

Comment: It's not really possible to change the I/O connections of an existing process.

Comment: It's possible, I have both processes under control (means I can implement anything) but i hope I can do it without any extra effort using current interface. (whic is application spawn subprocess and communicete using stdin/stdout)

Comment: The normal mechanism is fork, redirect I/O, exec. After you exec, you can't change the I/O connections from outside the process.

Comment: Seem the easiest way forget about attaching to stdin/stdout, making step back add implement option to communicate through socket instead spawning a new process.

Comment: If you can change the code of the child process you have many more options. I assumed you needed something that worked more generally.

Answer (score 0):

Attach as a debugger to the child process. Create new pipes for stdin, stdout, and stderr, and use `dup2` to put them in place. If you're on Linux 5.6 or newer, use `pidfd_getfd` to get the other ends of these pipes into your other process. Otherwise, send them as `SCM_RIGHTS` ancillary data over a Unix domain socket to your other process.